# Flume throw classpath not found error when using spooling

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, flume, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to use Flume on Windows (with the HDInsight Preview). I want to use the spooling directory to push files into HDFS.

Here is my config

```
agent.sources=s1                   
agent.channels=c1                  
agent.sinks=k1                     
agent.sources.s1.type=spooldir     
agent.sources.s1.spoolDir=c:\Hadoop
agent.channels.c1.type=memory      
agent.sinks.k1.type=hdfs           
agent.sinks.k1.channel=c1          
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.path=/Users/flu
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.inUsePrefix=inu
agent.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileSuffix=.dat
```

and here is my script

```
"C:\Hadoop\java\bin\java.exe" -Xmx20m -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///%CD%\conf\log4j.properties -    cp "C:\Hadoop\flume2\lib\*" org.apache.flume.node.Application -f C:\Hadoop\flume2\conf\test1.conf -n agent
```

But I keep getting an error

```
2013-11-28 22:31:15,341 (conf-file-poller-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.node.Poll
ingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingProperties
FileConfigurationProvider.java:145)] Failed to start agent because dependencies
 were not found in classpath. Error follows.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
       at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMet
ricsSystem.java:37)
```

I've never really used Java so I'm guessing it's a config issue but I'm totally stuck. Cheers.

EDIT This is the content of the flume lib directory

Directory of C:\Hadoop\flume2\lib

```
11/28/2013  10:28 PM    <DIR>          .
11/28/2013  10:28 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/27/2013  06:44 PM           346,729 apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM            95,536 apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM           304,810 apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM            43,033 asm-3.1.jar
03/16/2013  08:58 AM           116,219 aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM            16,679 async-1.3.1.jar
05/08/2013  11:15 PM           170,492 asynchbase-1.4.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           299,377 avro-1.7.3.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           186,572 avro-ipc-1.7.3.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM           229,116 bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM         1,663,318 bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM            92,027 boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar
06/23/2013  12:19 AM            22,043 cdk-morphlines-avro-0.4.0.jar
06/23/2013  12:19 AM           255,765 cdk-morphlines-core-0.4.0.jar
06/23/2013  12:19 AM            15,110 cdk-morphlines-solr-cell-0.4.0.jar
06/23/2013  12:19 AM            24,269 cdk-morphlines-solr-core-0.4.0.jar
06/23/2013  12:19 AM             7,573 cdk-morphlines-tika-core-0.4.0.jar
06/23/2013  12:19 AM            11,174 cdk-morphlines-tika-decompress-0.4.0.jar
06/23/2013  12:19 AM             7,736 cdk-morphlines-twitter-0.4.0.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM            41,123 commons-cli-1.2.jar
05/23/2013  09:35 AM           263,865 commons-codec-1.8.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           575,389 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:09 AM           241,367 commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           160,519 commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM            57,779 commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           163,151 commons-io-2.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           279,193 commons-lang-2.5.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM            60,686 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM            96,221 commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM           185,676 config-1.0.0.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM         2,671,577 derby-10.8.2.2.jar
03/05/2013  04:57 PM           313,898 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
06/25/2013  01:24 AM            20,430 flume-avro-source-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:23 AM           268,882 flume-file-channel-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:22 AM            62,999 flume-hdfs-sink-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:22 AM            13,532 flume-irc-sink-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:22 AM            53,389 flume-jdbc-channel-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:23 AM            25,553 flume-jms-source-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:22 AM            55,924 flume-ng-configuration-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:22 AM           339,790 flume-ng-core-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:23 AM            25,193 flume-ng-elasticsearch-sink-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:23 AM            20,266 flume-ng-embedded-agent-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:23 AM            45,705 flume-ng-hbase-sink-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:24 AM            16,413 flume-ng-log4jappender-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:23 AM            33,784 flume-ng-morphline-solr-sink-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:23 AM            31,105 flume-ng-node-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:21 AM           116,280 flume-ng-sdk-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:23 AM            44,406 flume-scribe-source-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:24 AM            56,652 flume-thrift-source-1.4.0.jar
06/25/2013  01:24 AM            15,636 flume-tools-1.4.0.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM           188,471 fontbox-1.7.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           189,285 gson-2.2.2.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM         1,501,575 guava-10.0.1.jar
10/22/2013  01:43 PM         4,126,926 hadoop-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
10/22/2013  01:43 PM         4,126,926 hadoop-core.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           427,021 httpclient-4.2.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           223,374 httpcore-4.2.1.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM            26,477 httpmime-4.2.3.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           132,202 irclib-1.10.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM           521,237 isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM            33,816 jackson-annotations-2.2.1.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM           192,105 jackson-core-2.2.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           228,268 jackson-core-asl-1.9.3.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM           864,931 jackson-databind-2.2.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           773,019 jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.3.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM            17,308 jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
03/05/2013  04:57 PM           153,253 jdom-1.0.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM            50,942 jempbox-1.7.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           539,912 jetty-6.1.26.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           177,131 jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           570,478 joda-time-2.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM            33,015 jsr305-1.3.9.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM           220,813 juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar
03/27/2013  06:44 PM           301,547 libthrift-0.7.0.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           481,535 log4j-1.2.16.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM         1,562,517 lucene-analyzers-common-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM         4,489,180 lucene-analyzers-kuromoji-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM            23,136 lucene-analyzers-phonetic-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM           296,556 lucene-codecs-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM         2,211,020 lucene-core-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM           107,729 lucene-grouping-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM           123,533 lucene-highlighter-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM            35,901 lucene-memory-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM            91,831 lucene-misc-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM           202,541 lucene-queries-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM           385,602 lucene-queryparser-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM            92,686 lucene-spatial-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM           142,262 lucene-suggest-4.3.0.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM           211,185 metadata-extractor-2.6.2.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM            85,309 metrics-core-3.0.0.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           644,934 mina-core-2.0.4.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM         4,326,608 netcdf-4.2-min.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           957,162 netty-3.4.0.Final.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM            22,545 noggit-0.5.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM           726,086 org.restlet-2.1.1.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM            19,672 org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.1.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM            29,555 paranamer-2.3.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM         3,910,899 pdfbox-1.7.1.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM         1,820,323 poi-3.8.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM           933,010 poi-ooxml-3.8.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM         4,706,775 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM         1,186,887 poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           450,279 protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM           208,025 rome-0.9.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           133,240 servlet-api-2.5-20110124.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM            25,496 slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM             9,753 slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           995,968 snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
06/23/2013  02:02 AM            29,880 solr-cell-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM         2,187,815 solr-core-4.3.0.jar
06/19/2013  02:47 AM           372,250 solr-solrj-4.3.0.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM            69,290 spatial4j-0.3.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM            90,722 tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM           475,853 tika-core-1.3.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM           486,107 tika-parsers-1.3.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM            30,679 tika-xmp-1.3.jar
02/22/2013  08:08 AM           449,505 velocity-1.7.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM            30,301 vorbis-java-core-0.1-tests.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM            47,478 vorbis-java-core-0.1.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM            14,752 vorbis-java-tika-0.1.jar
04/23/2013  09:25 PM           520,969 wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM         2,666,695 xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
04/23/2013  09:26 PM           117,333 xmpcore-5.1.2.jar
02/22/2013  08:09 AM            94,672 xz-1.0.jar
05/08/2013  11:16 PM           608,239 zookeeper-3.3.6.jar
         125 File(s)     65,826,273 bytes
           3 Dir(s)  16,852,574,208 bytes free
```

C:\Users\Chris>

Comment: Post the result of: dir C:\Hadoop\flume2\lib\*

Comment: try putting commons-configuration jar also in that dir. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/download_configuration.cgi

Comment: That seemed to work. Now I'm getting Flume errors but I'll put that in another question if I can't get to the bottom of it